# docker app builds but after running browser says This site can’t be reached

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

Docker creates image file and get run but no result on browser.

my Flask code

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host ='0.0.0.0', port = 5001,debug=True)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.8"
    services:
      app:
    build: .
    command: python app.py
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    volumes:
      - .:/python-flask
```

after giving command :- docker-compose up

Result:

Starting docker_demo_app_1 ... done
Attaching to docker_demo_app_1
app_1  |  * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
app_1  |  * Environment: production
app_1  |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
app_1  |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
app_1  |  * Debug mode: on
app_1  |  * Running on all addresses.
app_1  |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
app_1  |  * Running on http://172.18.0.2:5001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
app_1  |  * Restarting with stat
app_1  |  * Debugger is active!
app_1  |  * Debugger PIN: 103-335-354

When I run http://172.18.0.2:5001/ on browser it says -

```
This site can’t be reached
172.18.0.2 took too long to respond.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That

```
Running on http://172.18.0.2:5001/
```

is misleading. That's the IP address inside the container. If you're connecting from outside the container, use

```
http://127.0.0.1:5001/
```

which is local to the browser. If your browsing from elsewhere, substitute the IP address of the server that's running the docker image.

Answer (score 0):

0.0.0.0 will run on your machine’s IP address. To access your app via web browser , navigate to `http://<machineIP>:5001`